# Why GNU find -execdir command behave differently than BSD find?

Tags: find, osx, posix, gnu

On my OSX, I've installed GNU `find` next to default BSD `find` via: `brew install findutils`.

As far as I understand, BSD `find` is following POSIX standards and GNU makes it optional (as per this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18121/21471)), which makes a lot of inconsistencies in expected output.

For example:

#### BSD find

```
$ find -L /etc -execdir echo {} ';' | head
etc
AFP.conf
afpovertcp.cfg
aliases
aliases.db
apache2
extra
httpd-autoindex.conf
httpd-dav.conf
httpd-default.conf
```

#### GNU find

```
$ gfind --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 gfind -L /etc -execdir echo {} ';' | head
/etc
/etc/AFP.conf
/etc/afpovertcp.cfg
/etc/aliases
/etc/aliases.db
/etc/apache2
/etc/apache2/extra
/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-dav.conf
/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-default.conf
gfind: `echo' terminated by signal 13
gfind: `echo' terminated by signal 13
... endless loop here
```

Note: I'm using `-L` above as my `/etc` is link to `private/etc`.

In GNU find manual I can see that I can specify `POSIXLY_CORRECT` to follow POSIX standard, however this doesn't work for above example.

Any other way of forcing the same output (e.g. POSIX standard) for GNU find for above example?

Apart of endlessly looping, why GNU prints relative filenames and BSD prints full paths instead?

Comment: `-execdir` is not specified by POSIX.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas If `-execdir` is not POSIX and GNU find manual says it's implementing `-execdir 4.2.12 BSD`, why it's still working in completely different way if both are BSD implementations (e.g. printing absolute paths instead of relative)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not an *endless looping*, it's just GNU `find` reporting that `echo` died of a SIGPIPE (because the other end of the pipe on stdout has been closed when `head` died).

`-execdir` is not specified by POSIX. And even for `-exec`, there's nothing in [the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) that says that if the command is killed by a SIGPIPE, `find` should exit.

So, would POSIX specify `-execdir`, `gfind` would probably be more POSIX conformant than your BSD `find` (assuming your BSD find exits upon its child dying of a SIGPIPE as the wording of your question suggests, FreeBSD `find` doesn't in my tests and does run `echo` *in a loop* for every file (like for GNU find, not endless)).

You may say that for most common cases, `find` exiting upon a child dying of SIGPIPE would be preferable, but the `-exec`uted command could still die of a SIGPIPE for other reasons than the pipe on stdout being closed, so exiting `find` for that would be borderline acceptable.

With GNU `find`, you can tell `find` to quit if a command fails with:

```
find . ... \( -exec echo {} \; -o -quit \)
```

As to whether a `find` implementation is allowed or forbidden to report children dying of a signal on stderr, here (with the usage of `-execdir`) we're outside the scope of POSIX anyway, but if `-exec` was used in place of `-execdir`, it seems that would be a case where gfind is not conformant.

The spec for `find` says: *"the standard error shall be used only for diagnostic messages"* but also [says there](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_04):

> Default Behavior: When this section is listed as "The standard error shall be used only for diagnostic messages.", it means that, unless otherwise stated, the diagnostic messages shall be sent to the standard error only when the exit status indicates that an error occurred and the utility is used as described by this volume of POSIX.1-2008.

Which would indicate that since `find` doesn't return with a non-zero exit status in that case, it should not output that message on stderr.

Note that by that text, both GNU and FreeBSD `find` would be non-compliant in a case like:

```
$ find /dev/null -exec blah \;; echo "$?"
find: `blah': No such file or directory
0
```

where both report an error without settng the exit-status to non-zero. Which is why I [raised the question on the austin-group (the guys behind POSIX) mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/11809).

Note that if you change your command to:

```
(trap '' PIPE; find -L /etc -execdir echo {} \; | head)
```

`echo` will still be run for every file, will still fail, but this time, it will be `echo` reporting the error message.

---

Now about `filename` vs `/etc/filename` vs `./filename` being displayed.

Again, `-execdir` being not a *standard* option, there's no text that says who's right and who's wrong. `-execdir` was introduced by BSD `find` and copied later by GNU `find`.

GNU `find` has done some intentional changes (improvements) over it. For instance, it prepends file names with `./` in the arguments passed to commands. That means that `find . -execdir cmd {} \;` doesn't have a problem with filenames starting with `-` for instance.

The fact that `-L -execdir` doesn't pass a filepath relative to the parent directory is actually a [bug](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?27563) that affects version 4.3.0 to 4.5.8 of GNU `find`. It was fixed in 4.5.9, but that's on the development branch and there hasn't been a new *stable* release since (as of 2015-12-22, though [one is imminent](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.findutils.bugs/5882)).

[More info at the findutils mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.findutils.bugs/5833/focus=5891).

If all you want is print the base name of every file in `/etc` portably, you can just do:

```
find -L /etc -exec basename {} \;
```

Or more efficiently:

```
find -L ///etc | awk -F / '/\/\// && NR>1 {print last}
                          {if (NF > 1) last = $NF
                           else last = last "\n" $NF}
                          END {if (NR) print last}'
```

which you can simplify to

```
find -L /etc | awk -F / '{print $NF}'
```

if you can guarantee file paths don't contain newline characters (IIRC, some versions of OS/X had such files in /etc though).

GNUly:

```
find -L /etc -printf '%f\n'
```

---

As to whether:

```
find -exec echo {} \;
```

in the [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18121) you're referring to, is POSIX or not.

No, as a command invocation, that is not POSIX. A *script* that would have that would be non-compliant.

POSIX `find` requires that at least one path be given, but leaves the behaviour unspecified if the first non-option argument of `find` starts with `-` or is a `find` predicate (like `!`, or `(`), so GNU `find` behaviour *is* compliant, so are implementations that report an error (or treat the first argument as a file path even if it represents a find predicate) or spray red paint at your face, there's no reason `POSIXLY_CORRECT` would affect the `find` behaviour there.

Comment: @kenorb, ah, I missed the difference between filename vs filepath, focussing on the error message induced by the `|head`. The full path in `gfind -L` sound like something intentional. -execdir being not standard, there's no correct or incorrect as long as the behaviour matches the documentation

Comment: @kenorb, [I've raised the issue about errors about executing commands on the austin-group mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/11809)