# What Does the Output of "--help" Mean?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, arguments

When using the `--help` option of a terminal program, a lot of output is produced. It usually starts with `Usage:` and then a bunch of things and brackets and parentheses. My question is, what doe the brackets/parentheses mean? I believe that anything in between `[]` is optional, but could somebody explain what the rest means?

Comment: Probably a duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193815/how-do-i-use-man-pages-to-learn-how-to-use-commands, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17833/understand-synopsis-in-manpage

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but both of those questions have an answer that works for mine as well.
My mistake.