# Understanding the command "apt install curl nano unzip -y"

Tags: command-line, apt, curl, zip

I am trying to understand this command:

```
#apt install curl nano unzip -y
```

I think it to means install curl, unzip the archive and all questions answer yes.

Have I understood it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt` accepts multiple packages to install, this is what the `...` from `man apt` means:

> ```
> apt install pkg...
> ```

Your command will install the packages `curl`, `nano` and `unzip`. All questions (e.g. `Do you want to install ...`) will be answered with yes (`-y`).

---

Generally, if you want to understand commands, you should check the synopsis from the commands help or `man` page and [understand its syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17833/understand-synopsis-in-manpage).

I shortened the command from `man apt`, leaving out all optional commands, to make it more clear, the actual Synopsis is a bit more complicated:

```
 apt [-h] [-o=config_string] [-c=config_file] [-t=target_release]
 install pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...
```

Some very short explanation of that line (For more, see the Link above):

- `arg...` one or more of of `arg` accepted
- `[arg]` optional argument
- `arg | other_arg` one of `arg` or `other_arg`.

(and combinations of these).

Comment: Thank you all, too the corrector from my English...I wish all your a beautiful  Day!